# Magento 2.2.3 How to export products with SKU filter in admin?

Tags: product, filter, export, magento2.2.3, sku

[image]
Hi, I need to export products with .csv file. But I need to export products with specific SKU.
For example, I wanted to export the products which SKU was `60010`, `60012` and `45580`
I know I should apply filter for this. But I really tried to apply SKU filter but not working.
How can I apply multiple SKU filter?

Actually, its working with only one SKU filter, But I'm not sure how to separate each sku in the filter field.
I tried with `,` ,`;` and even `space`, i.e `60010, 60012, 45580`. But never worked. 
Can anyone please let me know how can I export these products by using SKU filter?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you need it for one time, you can use the Store Manager trial, it allows to perform search by SKUs and apply filter with the selected products. Then you can export products in a few clicks